# ASP.NET MVC Populate Html Attributes with model

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Instead of have "disabled="true"" hardcoded in the TextBoxFor element, I want it pulled from the Model.  The model property (Model.InvoicedApprovedBy) would be set to "" (enabled) or "disabled="disabled" (disabled)

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkingModel.Detail.ApprovedBy, new { id = "InvoiceApprovedBy", disabled="true", style = "width: 203px; " })%>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkingModel.Detail.ApprovedBy, new { id = "InvoiceApprovedBy", Model.InvoicedApprovedBy, style = "width: 203px; " })%>
```

It sets a html attribute called "InvoicedApprovedBy" instead of just placing the string "disabled="disabled"" into it.  How to I get it to place the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkingModel.Detail.ApprovedBy, new { id = "InvoiceApprovedBy",  disabled = Model.InvoicedApprovedBy, style = "width: 203px; " })%>
```

You won't need to set the model property to "disabled=disabled", just "disabled".

Comment: The element will always be disabled in this case.  I want to be able to have no "disabled =" as well.

Comment: The you're gonna have to get ugly: <input type="text" @(Model.Disabled ? "disabled=disabled" : "") /> you'll need a bool to do this.